# Auto Updation of Schema in Spring Data JPA(Addition of Foriegn Keys)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa. I am using two data sources so I have configured my own data sources and they are working. But When I am using two data sources, spring boot automatically is creating foriegn keys to my table. But when I have disabled the manual configuration & using the default data source, then it is not happening?  How do I change my code.

Here are my config class

**Primary**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.repository",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="primaryDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(primaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return tm;
    }

    @Bean(name="primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(DataSourceConfiguration.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

**Secondary**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.repository1",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
public class DS2Configuration {

    @Bean(name="secondaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(secondaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return tm;
    }

    @Bean(name="secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(DataSourceConfiguration.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

How do I change these so as to disable automatic foriegn key creation?

Comment: Because when using auto config `generateDdl` is set to `false` in your manual configuration you have set it to `true`.

Comment: Yes I fixed it earlier, forgot to update here. Anyways thanks for replying